# Use fields of outer query in group by of subquery

Tags: sqlite

My table: `CREATE TABLE T(id INT PRIMARY KEY, value INT UNIQUE)`

This query, as I considered, would produce a median value of `value` in the table. But sqlite v.3.9.1 gives me the error `no such column: ot.value` to the line with `group by`. And it process line with `where` successfully, although it uses a similar expression. What's the problem of the query?

```sql
select 
ot.id, 
ot.value
from T as ot
where (
    select count(c) > count(DISTINCT c) from (
        select count(*) c from T as it
        where it.value != ot.value
        group by it.value < ot.value
    ) LessMore
)
```

The same query succeeds in PostgreSQL and prints what was expected. MySQL gives the error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ot.value' in 'where clause'`

Comment: First of all, are you running MySQL or SQLite?  They're not the same thing.  And, what version of the database are you actually using?

Comment: As I said, I tried the query in MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL. And got a different result in each one

Comment: It works in PostgreSQL and throws slightly different errors in MySQL and SQLite

Comment: Again, what _version_ of MySQL are you using?  I can give a workaround using MySQL 8+.  I'm surprised that this query ran _anywhere_.

Comment: If you want to calculate a median, Sqlite doesn't have a built in aggregate function for the purpose, but it's easy to write a user defined one...